# c# prevent duplicating forms

Tags: c#, forms, button

I have 2 forms .. form1 and form2 .. I have button1 on form1 that loads form2 but every time I click button1 it loads new instance of form2

I want button1 to bring to front form2 if it was open and restore it if it was minimized

Comment: Good, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (haven't tested it though)

```
    public static bool _Invoked;
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_Invoked)
        {
            _Invoked = true;
            f2.Show();
        }
        else if (_Invoked)
        {
            f2.BringToFront();
            _Invoked = false;
        }
    }
```

Add a comment for further clarification

**EDIT:**

Just tested this and its working

```
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    bool _Clickone = false;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_Clickone)
        {
            _Clickone = true;
            f2.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            f2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            f2.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            f2.BringToFront();
        }
    }
```

Then handle the Form Closing event of the second for m

```
    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }
```

Comment: very perfect .. thank you Precious1tj

Comment: there's a problem .. when I click the button1 loads form2 normally and if I click it again it brings form2 to front again as needed to .. but if I closed form2 completely and go back to click button1 again it doesn't load form2 just do nothing ..

Comment: Try the second method. Make sure the Form_Closing Event of Form2

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating an onClose event in your form2, where you cancel the close, and set the visibility to hidden.

Then instead of creating a new instance, set the visibility to visible again.

Comment: can u show me the code to do this if u can plz